# SQLite.net connection pooling doesn't seem to work

Tags: sqlite, connection-pooling, sqlite.net

I'm using SQLite.net in my WFC project to write files to the DB on the local disk.
I thought I was getting slow writing performance because there was a new connection open for every db operation.
I tried using connection pooling in the following manner:

```
string dbConnectionString = $"Data Source={dbConfigPath};Version=3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=1000;";
```

However I'm not seeing any improvement.
Am I using it wrong? Is there a way to make sure the pooling is working?

Comment: Why are you re-opening the DB in the first place?

Comment: There are different modules that do operations with the DB. Also that is the way suggested to work in most discussions I [found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging I realized the main bottleneck came from the WCF service that I was using to run the insert queries.